# unable to assign a value in getOrElse path of Option if I use print statement in getOrElse

Tags: scala

I want to read a value from `application.conf`. If the value is not present, I want to assign a default value

```
val keyspaceOption:Option[String] = configuration.getOptional("db.keyspaceName")
  println(s"database will connect with keyspace ${keyspaceOption}")
  val keyspaceName = keyspaceOption.map(keyspace =>{
   keyspace
  })
    .getOrElse(
      println("unable to pick keyspace name from configuration. Using default value")
      "someDefaultName"
    )
  cassandraConnectionService.initKeySpace(cassandraSession,keyspaceName)
```

I am getting the following error in the code above

```
Error:(171, 7) ')' expected but string literal found.
      "someDefaultName"
```

If I remove the print statement in the `getOrElse` then it compiles. Why?

```
.getOrElse(//works
      //println("unable to pick keyspace name from configuration. Using default value")
      "someDefaultName"
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace

```
.getOrElse(
  println("unable to pick keyspace name from configuration. Using default value")
  "someDefaultName"
)
```

with

```
 .getOrElse{
      println("unable to pick keyspace name from configuration. Using default value");
      "someDefaultName"
 }
```

Comment: sorry, got it. I thought you recommended that I add a `;`. Noticed now that I had to change `()` with `{}`

Comment: Exactly. Take a look at this little snippet as well: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/DI40PjF/1